# PostSharp Caching MethodInterceptionAspect using ASP.NET Core in-memory cache

Tags: c#, .net-core, postsharp

```
public class CacheAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs methodInterceptionArgs)
    {
        if ((methodInterceptionArgs.Method.Name == CacheAspectAction.Get.ToString()) 
            //&& (Memory.Cache[cacheKey] != null)
            )
        {
        //    methodInterceptionArgs.ReturnValue = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
            return;
        }

        object returnVal = methodInterceptionArgs.Invoke(methodInterceptionArgs.Arguments);

        ClanCache(cacheKeyBase, cacheKey);

        if (returnVal != null)
            //Memory.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, returnVal, null, expirationInformation.AbsoluteExpiration, expirationInformation.SlidingExpiration);

        methodInterceptionArgs.ReturnValue = returnVal;
    }
}
```

How do I access the in-memory cache in ASP.NET Core from any class, including a PostSharp aspect? For example, I need to access [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in `MethodInterceptionAspect` and `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information about the problem you're facing and what solutions did you try so far? Is this about accessing ASP.NET Core [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1) instance that's provided via dependency injection? In this case I can refer you to the documentation about various techniques to consume dependencies in aspects: http://doc.postsharp.net/consuming-dependencies

Comment: Yes it about  ASP.NET Core IMemoryCache instance that's provided via dependency injection, and i did read the link you did send me and searched a but more infomation still not sure how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume here that you're using the built-in ASP.NET Core dependency injection and IMemoryCache implementation. However, the example can be easily adapted to other implementations. And I'm going to choose the [Global Service Locator](http://doc.postsharp.net/global-service-locator) approach for resolving dependencies in the aspect. Below is the modified example from the documentation page.

```
// A helper class that resolves services using built-in ASP.NET Core service provider.
public static class AspectServiceLocator
{
    private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public static void Initialize(IWebHost host)
    {
        serviceProvider = host.Services;
    }

    public static Lazy<T> GetService<T>() where T : class
    {
        return new Lazy<T>(GetServiceImpl<T>);
    }

    private static T GetServiceImpl<T>()
    {
        if (serviceProvider == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return (T) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(T));
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHost host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

        // Initialize the AspectServiceLocator during ASP.NET Core program start-up
        AspectServiceLocator.Initialize(host);

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}

[PSerializable]
public class CacheAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    private static Lazy<IMemoryCache> cache;

    static CacheAttribute()
    {
        // Use AspectServiceLocator to initialize the cache service field at application run-time.
        if (!PostSharpEnvironment.IsPostSharpRunning)
        {
            cache = AspectServiceLocator.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
        }
    }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        object cacheKey = args.Method.Name;
        object cachedResult;

        if (cache.Value.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out cachedResult))
        {
            args.ReturnValue = cachedResult;
            return;
        }

        args.Proceed();

        cache.Value.Set(cacheKey, args.ReturnValue);
    }
}
```